# how to display admob in VueJs component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cordova, admob

I have tried to add the admob to vuejs but the are no clear code of how to integrate it with vue component. I have checked from the internet and vueJs doesn't have clear solution for admob.

```
<template> <div> how admob Banner showing here </div> </template>
<script>
const admob = require("nativescript-admob");
    //import admob from 'nativescript-admob'
    export default  {
      name:'AdsPage',
      mounted() {
        setTimeout(() => {
        admob.createBanner({
       // if this 'view' property is not set, the banner is overlayed on the current top most view
       // view: ..,
       testing: true, // set to false to get real banners
       size: 550, // anything in admob.AD_SIZE, like admob.AD_SIZE.SMART_BANNER
       androidBannerId: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111", // add your own
       margins: {
        // if both are set, top wins
        //top: 10
        bottom: 50
      },
      }).then(
        function() {
          console.log("admob createBanner done");
        },
       function(error) {
         console.log("admob createBanner error: " + error);
        }
     )
        },5000)
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried building your app and then checking if the banner shows on your test device?

For me in Vue the banner wasn't showing but when I ran my code in Xcode (for iOS) it worked perfectly.

Also make sure your  has position relative!

Comment: I have fixed it now it is working perfectly in android so I did it in a different way other than the usual Adsense in the web page.